Сосредоточенна: одно или два "н"?
Вопрос по удвоенному "н". Как правильно в данном предложении:
Но в этот момент я была напряжена и сосредоточенна.

Правильно:
Но в этот момент я была напряжена и сосредоточенна.
Пояснение
В обоих случаях краткое прилагательное, но формы письма разные, проверка по словарю.
Русский орфографический словарь
сосредоточенный; кр. ф. прич. -ен, -ена; кр. ф. прил. -ен, -ена (с дополн.: она сосредоточена на своей работе) и -ен, -енна (без дополн.: она молчалива и сосредоточенна)
напряжённый; кр. ф. -ён, -ена (напрягшийся: паруса, мышцы, нервы напряжены; внимание напряжено) и -ён, -ённа (отношения напряжённы; работа, борьба напряжённа; выражение лица напряжённо)
НАПРЯЖЁННЫЙ, -ая, -ое. 1. -жён, -жена, -жено. Находящийся в состоянии напряжения. Н-ые мускулы, струны. Н-ые руки, ноги. Н-ое тело. // Находящийся в состоянии внутреннего напряжения, связанный с таким состоянием. Н-ое внимание. Н. интерес
